# How to split a string after specific character in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I strip a string after the 3rd /. This is what I've got so far:

```
   RIGHT(dp.PageAssociation,LEN(dp.PageAssociation)-CHARINDEX('/',dp.PageAssociation))
```

The above query strips it after the 1st / instead of the 3rd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

may by so:

```
CHARINDEX('/',dp.PageAssociation,(CHARINDEX('/',dp.PageAssociation,(CHARINDEX('/',dp.PageAssociation)+1))+1))
```

**EDIT 2:**

on your example:

```
SELECT RIGHT(dp.PageAssociation,LEN(dp.PageAssociation)-CHARINDEX('/',dp.PageAssociation,(CHARINDEX('/',dp.PageAssociation,(CHARINDEX('/',dp.PageAssociation)+1))+1)))
```

can it work?

Comment: How do I actually get the string from it?

Comment: This still just gets everything after the 1st /